# Why does Spring @Cacheable not pass the annotated method's result type to its deserializer?

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

This is sample code with Kotlin.

**@Configuration**

```
@Bean("cacheManager1hour")
fun cacheManager1hour(@Qualifier("cacheConfig") cacheConfiguration: RedisCacheConfiguration, redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory): CacheManager {
    cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(60 * 60))
    return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration)
            .build()
}

@Bean("cacheConfig")
fun cacheConfig(objectMapper:ObjectMapper): RedisCacheConfiguration {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .computePrefixWith { cacheName -> "yaya:$cacheName:" }
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(StringRedisSerializer()))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()))

}
```

**@RestController**

```
@Cacheable(value = "book", key = "#root.methodName", cacheManager = "cacheManager1hour")
fun getBook(): Book {
    return Book()
}

class Book  {
    var asdasd:String? = "TEST"
    var expires_in = 123
}
```

The `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` cannot process the "kotlin class" and we need to add '@class as property' to the Redis cache entry.

Anyway, why do we need the `@class`? The Spring context is aware of the result's type, why doesn't it get passed? We would have two benefits:

1. less memory
2. easy for the Serializer, i.e. `objectMapper.readValue(str, T)`

**Annotated Spring code for illustration**

```
// org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport
@Nullable
private Cache.ValueWrapper findInCaches(CacheOperationContext context, Object key) {
    for (Cache cache : context.getCaches()) {
        // --> maybe we can pass the context.method.returnType to doGet
        Cache.ValueWrapper wrapper = doGet(cache, key); 
        if (wrapper != null) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Cache entry for key '" + key + "' found in cache '" + 
        cache.getName() + "'");
            }
            return wrapper;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache
@Override
protected Object lookup(Object key) { 
    // -> there will get the deserialized type can pass to Jackson

    byte[] value = cacheWriter.get(name, createAndConvertCacheKey(key));

    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return deserializeCacheValue(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return type could be:

- some abstract class
- some interface

In those cases your return type is almost useless to deserialize the object. Encoding the actual class always works .